# Constant SIGSEGV or SIGILL errors in chrome 111 + apps crashing randomly

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, segmentation-fault

Here's one of the var/logs/syslog's during a chrome crash
https://justpaste.it/55bs3

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 using Kernel 6.1.1 (have to use this newer one to fix snap packages crashing)

I also got the following log when Google Earth crashed:
https://justpaste.it/de3vc

Is there something I can do to fix these?

Comment: Sorry I do not see anything in these logs that relates to why they are crashing and involves the Ubuntu OS. Please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

It was the RAM. It was faulty, I replaced it and this is not happening anymore.